# An issue while trying to print appended array elements in c

Tags: c

I was trying to make an array that contains Fibonacci numbers in C, but I got into trouble. I can't get all of the elements, and some of the elements are wrongly calculated, and I don't know where I am I going wrong.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void){
    int serie[]={1,1},sum=0,size=2;
    while(size<=4000000){
        serie[size]=serie[size-1]+serie[size-2];
        printf("%d\n",serie[size-1]);
        size+=1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
1
2
4
6
11
17
28
45
73
118
191
309
500
809
1309
2118
3427
5545
8972
14517
23489
38006
61495
99501
160996
260497
421493
681990
1103483
1785473
2888956
4674429
7563385
12237814
19801199
32039013
51840212
83879225
135719437
219598662
355318099
574916761
930234860
1505151621
-1859580815
-354429194
2080957287
1726528093
-487481916
1239046177
751564261
1990610438
-1552792597
437817841
-1114974756
-677156915
-1792131671
1825678710
33547039
1859225749
1892772788
-542968759
1349804029
806835270
-2138327997
-1331492727
825146572
-506346155
318800417
-187545738
131254679
-56291059
74963620
18672561
93636181
112308742
205944923
318253665
524198588
842452253
1366650841
-2085864202
-719213361
1489889733
770676372
-2034401191
-1263724819
996841286
-266883533
729957753
463074220
1193031973
1656106193
-1445829130
210277063
-1235552067
-1025275004
2034140225
1008865221
-1251961850
-243096629
-1495058479
-1738155108
1061753709
-676401399
385352310
-291049089
94303221
-196745868
-102442647
-299188515
-401631162
-700819677
-1102450839
-1803270516
1389245941
-414024575
975221366
561196791
1536418157
2097614948
-660934191

--------------------------------
Process exited after 2.345 seconds with return value 3221225477
Press any key to continue . . .
```

I don't understand why it is giving that output.

Comment: `int serie[]={1,1}` has 2 elements, its size is `2`, you dont change that by incrementing the variable `size`

Comment: UB by accessing elements outside the array.

Comment: if you just want to print on the screen then you dont need the array but only the last two values so you can compute the next one

Comment: i used the size variable to use it while declaring elements. Isn't it a way? PS: i know that i don't need array but im just practicing.

Comment: You can't append elements to an array. Arrays have fixed sizes.

Comment: @melpomene i got it. thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int serie[]={1,1}
```

Declares an array of two elements. As the array has two elements and indices start from zero, it has valid indices - 0 and 1, ie. `serie[0]` is the first element and `serie[1]` is the second element.

```
int size=2;
while(..) {
   serie[size]= ...
   size+=1;
}
```

As `size` starts `2`, the expression `serie[2] =` is invalid. There is no third element in the array and it writes to an unknown memory region. Executing such an action is [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). There could be some another variable there, some system variable, or memory of another program or it can spawn nasal demons. It is undefined.

If you want to store the output in an array, you need to make sure the array has enough elements to hold the input.

And a tip:

```
int serie[4000000];
```

may not work, as it will try to allocate `40000000 * sizeof(int)`, which assuming `sizeof(int) = 4` is 15.2 megabytes of memory. Some systems don't allow to allocate that much memory on stack, so you should move to dynamic allocation.

Comment: Thats the answer that im looking for. Thanks.

Comment: @EmreUYGUN - If this is the answer you were looking for, (And if it is correct.) you can accept it as the answer by clicking the hollow accept button to the upper left side of the question.

Answer (score 0):

You're having an integer overflow because the `int` size is ,at a certain leverl, not big enough to hold the numbers, so the number is wrapping round the size and giving false values.

Your program should be like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void){
    long long unsigned series[100] = {1,1};
    int size = 2;

    while(size < 100){
        series[size] = series[size-1] + series[size-2];
        printf("%llu\n", series[size-1]);
        size += 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Although, size of `long long unsigned` is also limited, at a certain level, with such very big numbers in Fibonacci. So this will result in more correct numbers printed, but also will overflow at a certain level. It will overflow when the number exceeds this constant `ULLONG_MAX` declared in `limits.h`.

Comment: I don't understand what exactly you are meaning. I think my writing operations is within the 100-element boundaries of the array.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. My comment makes no sense. I'll delete it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void){
    int serie[]={1,1},sum=0,size=2;
    while(size<=4000000){
        serie[size]=serie[size-1]+serie[size-2];
        printf("%d\n",serie[size-1]);
        size+=1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

... is that it attempts to store a very long series of numbers (4 million) into a very short array (2 elements). Arrays are fixed in size. Changing the variable `size` has no effect on the size of the array `serie`.

The expression `serie[size]=...` stores numbers outside the bounds of the array **every time it's executed** because the only legal array index values are 0 and 1. This results in *undefined behavior* and to be honest you were lucky only to see weird output.

There are a couple of possible solutions. The one that changes your code the least is to simply extend the array. Note that I've made it a static rather than automatic variable, because your implementation probably won't support something of that size in its stack.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int serie[4000000]={1,1};

int main(void){
    int size=2;
    while(size<4000000){ // note strict less-than: 4000000 is not a valid index
        serie[size]=serie[size-1]+serie[size-2];
        printf("%d\n",serie[size-1]);
        size+=1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The more general solution is to store the current term and the two previous terms in the series as three separate integers. It's a little more computationally expensive but doesn't have the huge memory requirement.

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int term0=0, term1=1, term2;
    while(1)
    {
        if (term0 > INT_MAX - term1) break;// overflow, stop
        term2 = term0 + term1;

        printf("%d\n",term2);
        term0 = term1;
        term1 = term2;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This also has the benefit that it won't print any numbers that have "wrapped around" as a result of exceeding the limits of what can be represented in an 'int`. Of course, you can easily choose another data type in order to get a longer sequence of valid output.

Comment: Still, @melpomene?

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems:

- You need to allocate more space in `serie`, as much as you are going
  to use
- Eventually the fib numbers will become too big to fit inside an integer, even a 64bit unsigned integer (long long unsigned), i think 90 or so is about max

See the modified code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

// Set maximum number of fib numbers
#define MAX_SIZE 90

int main(void) {
    // Use 64 bit unsigned integer (can't be negative)
    long long unsigned int serie[MAX_SIZE];
    serie[0] = 1;
    serie[1] = 1;

    int sum = 0;
    int size = 0;

    printf("Fib(0): %llu\n", serie[0]);
    printf("Fib(1): %llu\n", serie[1]);

    for (size = 2; size < MAX_SIZE; size++) {
        serie[size] = serie[size-1] + serie[size-2];

        printf("Fib(%i): %llu\n", size, serie[size]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

As you are only printing out the numbers, you don't actually have to store all of them
(only the two previous numbers), but it really doesn't matter if there's only 90.